# Jenkinsfile - Agents questions

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two questions to following example:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "docker" }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3.5.0-jdk-8'
                }
            }
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question 1:**

When I declare agent in top level of Jenkinsfile it means that it will be used for all below stages. So what is difference between:

```
agent { label "docker" }
```

and

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3.5.0-jdk-8'
    }
}
```

First one will use docker agent and second will use docker agent with maven image as executable environment? Where label "docker" agent is configured/installed?

**Question 2:**

How **label** tag is working? I know that somewhere is already created agent and using label I just point to it - like in example above: by default I use "docker" agent? it also means that during `steps {...}` this agent will be overridden by **maven** agent?

**Question 3:**

Last question for following example:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
       docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v ... -e ...'
       }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Maven Build') {
            steps {
                sh '...'
            }
        }
        stage('Docker push') {
            agent { 
                docker 'openjdk:8-jdk-alpine' 
            } 
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.build("my-image")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to build first stage using docker container with **maven:3-alpine** image. During build following error is printed:

```
...tmp/durable-54b54bdc/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
```

So I modified this example, here is the working result:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Docker push') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.build("my-image")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How is it working **agent any** in this case? Which agent can execute docker.build?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

```
agent { label "docker" }
```

This will try to find an agent with label `docker` and execute the steps in that agent.

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3.5.0-jdk-8'
    }
}
```

This will try to pull the docker image with name `maven:3.x.x` and start the container and execute the steps mentioned in the pipeline. If you are using `MultiJob` this will be executed in the slave with the label based on this configuration:

[image]

**Answer 2:**

Defining `agent`  at the top-level of the Pipeline ensures that an Executor will be assigned to the agent labeled `docker`. To my knowledge, I assume that docker container will be created in the agent labeled `docker` and steps will be executed inside the container.

**Answer 3:**

The reason could be, you may not have configured `Docker Label` (refer above image). The task could have executed in the master where the docker is not installed. The reason for other one working could be because, the job is executed in an agent where docker is installed.